Adding a readable store to writable store
I'm trying to add a readable store as a default value to a writable store, so that the user will see some default value when he opens the app.
I have one large readable store - taskStore, which contains different objects with task information, as follows:
import { writable, readable } from "svelte/store";

// The video directories together with the corresponding frame counts should be placed here
export const taskStore = readable(
    [ 
        {
            imageDir: '100159',
            frameCount: 50,
            labels: [
                { frame: 10, x: 125, y: 60 },
                { frame: 10, x: 125, y: 60 },
                { frame: 10, x: 125, y: 60 },
            ]
        },
        {
            imageDir: '100589', 
            frameCount: 50, 
            labels: []
        }
    ]
)



So I tried adding the first value of the taskStore to the writable currentTaskStore, like this:
export const currentTaskStore = writable([taskStore[0]])

but it doesn't work, and I get the undefined value when I try to use this store in other components. Is it possible to use a writable store with complicated objects, or are they for primitives only?

Outside of components you can only access the value of stores via subscribe or the get helper function (from svelte/store), which just creates a temporary subscription.
So if you do get(taskStore)[0], this should work.
Stores can hold any kind of object.
